# Build failed in Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I am working on a rails application. All processes were successful until I was to push which is giving me this error, no default language detected for this app. [image]

I checked out the heroku devcenter and added a ruby buildpack but it wasn't working still.
help pls

Comment: 1. You are developing in the `develop` git branch, not master. Heroku requires the changes to be in master. 2. What are the files you have versioned and committed in master? Provide a git root folder overview of your master branch.

Comment: yeah, my bad, I was trying to deploy from develop... I have pushed to master and it is working now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try go to `config/applicaion.rb` and set     `config.i18n.locale = ?` where `?` is your locale language (symbolized 4 ex `:en`).